# PHP loads a page before redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

For example, I have this route on web.php:

```
Route::redirect('google', 'http://www.google.com')
```

If go to this route by entering the URL it quickly displays a page saying "Redirecting to http://www.google.com" and then it redirects.

When I was working locally this did not happen. But once I deployed into the server, it started to happen.

Comment: It's due to slow Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't see it in the local because it happened to fast.